# IP routing table is empty

Tags: networking

I've just opened the pi for the first time, with Raspbian Buster Lite. When I type `route -n` I get:

```
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
```

I would expect to see the gateway ip here.

If if try `sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1` I get `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`.

Some context: I'm trying to ssh into the pi, without success so far even though ssh is enabled. 
(`getting a ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.x.xxx port 22: Connection refused`)

Comment: Routing table can only be empty if you have no network interfaces that are up. How do you plan to connect to the network anyway? WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials to setup the pi with wifi, I gave up on solving this with wifi alone and ended up connecting the pi via ethernet cable. Just plug the cable and that's it!

Now `route -n` returns two rows.

(I will not mark my answer as accepted, as perhaps there are better ways to solve this)

Comment: Do you had a problem with wifi? It wasn't clear from the question. So your solution is to use the wired connection instead of wifi?

Comment: The pi was never connected to the internet in any way. And I was trying to setup it up for the first time using wifi. I didn't manage, while with ethernet is automatic, just plug the cable and the pi gets the default gateway.

Comment: Something confusing in my question (which now I edited) is that I was initially thinking to have the pi connected, but this was not true.

Comment: @Rexcirus, I have EXACTLY the same output to those commands, except I'm running CentOS in a virtualbox VM (not rasp pi).  No way to plug a physical ethernet in.  Any guess what's wrong in this case?

Comment: @Ingo I have EXACTLY the same output to those commands as Rexcirus, except I'm running CentOS in a virtualbox VM (not rasp pi). No way to plug a physical ethernet in. Any guess what's wrong in this case?

Comment: @mike_butak Please create a new question about your issue. It's a complete different setup with a virtual machine and comments are not the right place to answer a question.

Comment: Sure @Ingo, it's here; https://serverfault.com/questions/1044733/why-cant-my-virtualbox-centos-communicate-with-network-internet?noredirect=1#comment1359985_1044733